# Hide checkbox only from header row of a slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

[image]

**Code1:**

```
var checkboxSelector = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({
                                                          cssClass: "slick-cell-checkboxsel"

                                                      });

tempColumns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition());
```

**Code2:**

```
    tempGrid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({selectActiveRow:false}));
tempGrid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);
```

I am using the above code to show the checkbox column.

How to hide checkbox only from header row of a slickgrid? (under red circle in the image)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
grid.onHeaderRowCellRendered.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            if (args.column.id === '_checkbox_selector') {
                // do something if you want
            } else {
                $(args.node).empty();
                $('<input type="text">')
                    .data('columnId', args.column.id)
                    .val(columnFilters[args.column.id])
                    .appendTo(args.node);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your code.  How/why does this answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this, but my solution was to comment out a few lines in the `slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js` file. From what I can tell, `handleSelectedRowsChanged()` actually rewrites the contents of the checkbox cell header with a new `<input>` element on every change -- it doesn't just change the checked attribute. So I've commented out the lines in that function that make the swap, as well as a few others that add the checkbox at init and the event to (de)select all.

https://gist.github.com/1085623

There's probably a better way to approach this, but I needed to get something out the door ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to remove the checkbox.

```
$('.slick-header-columns input[type="checkbox"]').remove();
```

However, that checkbox on the header row allows you to do "Check All". Are you sure you want to remove it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately your method is not safe, i.e. when you select last row's checkbox, the checkbox appears in the header.

Can you suggest me how can I add a column of checkbox without using Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn?

Comment: That would be rather complicated and could break other parts of the control. You might ask someone on their support forum. http://groups.google.com/group/slickgrid?pli=1